# Why weren't Gemini capsules given names?

Tags: project-gemini, crew-module

Mercury capsules had names (e.g. [*Liberty Bell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Redstone_4)).

Apollo command modules had names (e.g. [*Columbia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11)).

Apollo lunar modules had names (e.g. [*Challenger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_17)).

Space Shuttle orbiters had names (e.g. [*Columbia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Columbia) and [*Challenger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Challenger)).

**Why didn't the Gemini capsules have names?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Actually, the first manned one ([Gemini 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_3)) did have a name, "Molly Brown<sup>1</sup>".

According to an [article](https://books.google.com/books?id=9VMEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA111&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=true) in Life Magazine, Oct 11, 1968, "Spacecraft Anonymous", upper NASA management became weary of arguing about spacecraft names with the crew after Grissom decided to name his capsule that.

[image]

<sup>1</sup> "Molly Brown" was a reference to the movie and play "[The Unsinkable Molly Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unsinkable_Molly_Brown_(film))" which is a joking reference to the sinking of Grissom's capsule on his Mercury flight.  The title character is a survivor of the sinking of the Titanic.

Comment: As I recall, NASA management initially objected to Grissom's name of Molly Brown and asked him for his second choice, to which he responded "How about the Titanic?".  Grissom was a character. Molly Brown it is!

Answer (score 22):

Supplemental to Organic Marble's answer:

The Gemini no-names policy remained in effect through the early part of the Apollo program as well; the Apollo 7 and 8 spacecraft were nameless. The names returned when Apollo missions started flying two spacecraft independently; for the CSM-only missions, the call sign was simply "Apollo 7" or “Apollo 8”, but with a CSM and LM both on the air, they needed separate call signs. The pre-landing spacecraft got somewhat irreverent names ("Gumdrop" and "Spider" for A9, "Charlie Brown" and "Snoopy" for A10), but the remaining Apollo flights were named with management-acceptable levels of gravitas.

After the landings, the Skylab and ASTP flights went back to generic call signs. I believe the Skylab call signs were "Skylab 2/3/4" even while the crew was in the CSM, but I'm not certain.

Once NASA was flying reusable spacecraft, it made more sense to give them individual names.

Comment: The next big argument was about "ISS" / "Space Station Alpha".